# Querying Current Wifi Network SSID for Network Profiles script

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, wifi

I've got a script that programmatically applies different proxy settings for different wifi networks, but I'd like to make it automatic; when a certain wifi network is logged into, my script is called with the network name.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are on a linux `if-up/if-down` hooks is what you need.
Look at `/etc/network/if-up.d` and `/etc/network/if-down.d` .
The [interfaces(5)](http://www.digipedia.pl/man/doc/view/interfaces.5/) manual page whould help in general.